# Gulp: error in console, assert.js:90 throw new assert.AssertionError

Tags: javascript, gulp

I get such an error in console:
$ gulp

```
assert.js:90
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: Task function must be specified

at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\user\Projects\New project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)

at Gulp.task (C:\Users\user\Projects\New project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Projects\New project\gulpfile.js:44:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var build = require('gulp-build');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var browser_sync = require('browser-sync');
var gulps = require("gulp-series");


//gulp-build
gulp.task('build', function() {
    gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
        .pipe(build({
            GA_ID: '123456'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

//gulp-sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

//gulp-browser-sync
gulp.task('browser_sync', function() {
    var files = [
        '*.html',
        'css/*.css'
    ];
    browser_sync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
});

//gulp-watch
gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

//gulp-series
gulps.registerTasks({
    "test1": (function(done) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("test1 is done");
            done();
        }, 1000);
    }),
    "test2": (function() {
        console.log("test2 is done");
    })
});

gulps.registerSeries("default", ["test1", "test2"]);

// gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'browser_sync'], function() {});
```

I'm just a beginner, have you any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: A great article which might help:
https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/

Comment: @SurajRao: This is a formal comment. In this case it is NOT NEEDED. A link is sufficient. "Michael Oxborrow" - good link, tnx.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you use gulp 4 with the gulp 3 'syntax'.
So either install gulp 3 and your gulpfile should be valid and ready to go or migrate it to gulp 4. [Here](https://blog.wearewizards.io/migrating-to-gulp-4-by-example) is a good article about that.

[Changelog](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400) of gulp

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Where can I find gulp 4 syntax? Is there a site, library with prepared functions?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found it. Sorry for stupid questions. :)

Comment: If someone else will maintain its own project at gulp@3.*, just install the correct version: `npm i -D gulp@3.*`

Answer (score 11):

gulp 4 series(...tasks)

```
gulp.task('one', function(done) {
// do stuff
done();
});

gulp.task('two', function(done) {
// do stuff
done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('one', 'two', function(done) {
// do more stuff
done();
}));
```

see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md

Answer (score 3):

gulp automatically installs version 4.0.0

change the version of your gulp by running below command

```
 npm install gulp@3.3.4 --save
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: my answer helped someone. Good to hear that. @AkshayVijayJain

Comment: No need to specify minor versions: `npm i -D gulp@3.*`

Comment: @giovannipds, It is left to you which version to choose.I just gave an example. Thank you

Comment: @BasavarajHadimani I know you did, but we're intended to give the best full answers here. I would recommend update it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue using below command

```
npm install --save-dev gulp@3.9.1
```

This will solve your problem (I resolved issue in window 7 and window 10)

Comment: No need to specify minor versions: `npm i -D gulp@3.*`

Answer (score 0):

Just passed for the same error now, [DAXaholic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38182845/842768) is right, your `gulpfile.js`'s gulp@3.* but you have installed gulp 4. Just install the correct version:

```sh
npm i -D gulp@3.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in the package.json to install old or latest version of Gulp as below:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
```

check your CLI Version and Local version of Gulp with gulp -v command.

> CLI version 3.9.1
>
> Local version 3.9.1

```
if it's not equal this error may occur.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also an important thing to notice, if you get the

"AssertionError: Task never defined: two"

Probably it's because the tasks should be in sequence, so first task one task two and then the task with the

gulp.series('one', 'two')

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem with:

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -D
npx -p touch nodetouch gulpfile.js
```

The default installation commands available at gulp.js
Hope it helps,

Comment: This would still install `gulp@4.*` nowadays, so it's not an appropriated answer anymore.